# Proof that the $sqrt[k]{z}\, z \in \mathbb N$ counts the amount of numbers less than or equal to z with a $k-$exact power

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing, proof-verification, alternative-proof

Empirically, it can shown that
$$\mathrm{Floor}[\sqrt[k]{z} ] \,, z \wedge k\in \mathbb N $$
is equal to the amount of numbers which have a $k-$exact root. For example, $\sqrt 36 = 6$ means that there are six numbers whose square root is exact (or 2-exact numbers), namely 36, 25, 16, 9, 4, and 1, with corresponding square roots as 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1. For $\sqrt[3] 343 = 7$, with the 3-exact numbers being 343, 216, 125, 64, 27, 8 and 1. And so on.

 
**Proof**

Proceeding by cases

Case I: $z=y^k$, that is, $z$ an exact power of the $k-$root function
$$\sqrt[k]{y^k}=y$$

Case II: $z \gtrapprox y^k$, that is, $z$ is somehow larger than the closest (from below) $k-$exact power. Let $z=y^k+x\,, x\in \mathbb N$, so 
$$\sqrt[k]{y^k+x}]= y\sqrt[k]{1+\frac{x}{y^k}}]$$ 
and $\mathrm{Floor}[y\sqrt[k]{1+\frac{x}{y^k}}] = y$.

Case III: $z \lessapprox y^k$, that is, $z$ is slightly smaller than the nearest $k-$ exact power (from above). Choose $z = y_*^k -x$, so
$$\mathrm{Floor}[y_*\sqrt[k]{1-\frac{x}{y_*^k}}] = y_*$$
Notice that $y_* < y$ the "$y$" used for cases I and II. 

Q.E.D.

**QUESTION**

Now then, how come that either $y$ or $y_*$ can actually represent the amount of numbers with $k-$exact root? where is the counting capability of this number? I don't quite completely grasp that capability from the way I wrote this proof. So maybe my proof lacks to be written in a more formal way, or in some other way, or perhaps is plainly wrong, because of the explicit or implicit assumptions that I am making, are not those necessary and/or sufficient to express the counting capability that was shown empirically.

Thanks!

Comment: It looks to me that the property you are "proving" is a trivial consequence from the fact that $\sqrt[k]{n}$ is monotonously increasing with $n$. The list of k-exact numbers not bigger than n is $1^{k},2^{k},...,Floor[\sqrt[k]{n}]^{k}$, so it's easy to count them.

Comment: @citronrose , so, if it is a fact, then either it can be taken as an axiom, or is something that has already been proven in some other ways. By the form you answered, I feel that it can be taken as a self-evident given, and so, any proof attempt would be either irrelevant, or it would be condemned to fall into a kind of "Bourbakinism" or "Russell-Whitehead-ism, principia-mathematica" style of proof. OK, fair enough. Thank you!